# Minikube never start - Error restarting cluster

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I'm using Arch linux
I had virtualbox 5.2.12 installed
I had the minikube 0.27.0-1 installed
I had the Kubernetes v1.10.0 installed

When i try start the minkube with `sudo minikube start` i get this error

```
Starting local Kubernetes v1.10.0 cluster...
Starting VM...
Getting VM IP address...
Moving files into cluster...
Setting up certs...
Connecting to cluster...
Setting up kubeconfig...
Starting cluster components...
E0527 12:58:18.929483   22672 start.go:281] Error restarting cluster:  running cmd: 
sudo kubeadm alpha phase certs all --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml &&
sudo /usr/bin/kubeadm alpha phase kubeconfig all --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml &&
sudo /usr/bin/kubeadm alpha phase controlplane all --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml &&
sudo /usr/bin/kubeadm alpha phase etcd local --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml
: running command: 
sudo kubeadm alpha phase certs all --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml &&
sudo /usr/bin/kubeadm alpha phase kubeconfig all --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml &&
sudo /usr/bin/kubeadm alpha phase controlplane all --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml &&
sudo /usr/bin/kubeadm alpha phase etcd local --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml
: exit status 1
```

I already try start minekube with others option like:

```
sudo minikube start --kubernetes-version v1.10.0 --bootstrapper kubeadm

sudo minikube start --bootstrapper kubeadm

sudo minikube start --vm-driver none

sudo minikube start --vm-driver virtualbox

sudo minikube start --vm-driver kvm

sudo minikube start --vm-driver kvm2
```

Always I get the same error. Can someone help me?

Comment: I suggest to delete the existing VM and let minikube recreate a new one.

Comment: If you are interested in finding the root of the problem with starting your Minikube, I suggest you increasing the level of debugging information. You may try to run:
minikube -v=4 --log_dir <logdirectory> start, then logs comes then to <logdirectory> and you may post it here to analyze by community

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Minikube VM is usually started for simple experiments without any important payload.
That's why it's much easier to recreate minikube cluster than trying to fix it.

To delete existing minikube VM execute the following command:

```
minikube delete
```

This command shuts down and deletes the minikube virtual machine. No data or state is preserved.

Check if you have all dependencies at place and run command:

```
minikube start
```

This command creates a “kubectl context” called “minikube”. This context contains the configuration to communicate with your minikube cluster. minikube sets this context to default automatically, but if you need to switch back to it in the future, run:

```
kubectl config use-context minikube
```

Or pass the context on each command like this:

```
kubectl get pods --context=minikube
```

More information about command line arguments can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/minikube/#installation).

Comment: I ran into the same error, the minikube delete, start solved the issue, other things I have done before this command to turn on VBox and docker container (last step may not be relevant), just sharing my steps

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

The below answer did not work due to what I suspect are differences in versions between my environment and the information I found and I'm not willing to sink more time into this problem. **The VM itself does startup** so if you have important information in it, ie: other docker containers you can login to the VM and extract such data from it before `minikube delete`

---

Same problem, I ssh'ed into the VM and ran
`sudo kubeadm alpha phase certs all --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml`
The result was
`failure loading apiserver-kubelet-client certificate: the certificate has expired`

So like any good engineer, I googled that and found this:

Source: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/581

> If you are using a version of kubeadm prior to 1.8, where I understand certificate rotation #206 was put into place (as a beta
>   feature) or your certs already expired, then you will need to manually
>   update your certs (or recreate your cluster which it appears some (not
>   just @kachkaev) end up resorting to).
>
> You will need to SSH into your master node. If you are using kubeadm
>
> > = 1.8 skip to 2.
>
> Update Kubeadm, if needed. I was on 1.7 previously. $ sudo curl -sSL
>   https://dl.k8s.io/release/v1.8.15/bin/linux/amd64/kubeadm >
>   ./kubeadm.1.8.15 $ chmod a+rx kubeadm.1.8.15 $ sudo mv
>   /usr/bin/kubeadm /usr/bin/kubeadm.1.7 $ sudo mv kubeadm.1.8.15
>   /usr/bin/kubeadm Backup old apiserver, apiserver-kubelet-client, and
>   front-proxy-client certs and keys. $ sudo mv
>   /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.key
>   /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.key.old $ sudo mv
>   /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt
>   /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt.old $ sudo mv
>   /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt
>   /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt.old $ sudo mv
>   /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.key
>   /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.key.old $ sudo mv
>   /etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.crt
>   /etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.crt.old $ sudo mv
>   /etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.key
>   /etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.key.old Generate new apiserver,
>   apiserver-kubelet-client, and front-proxy-client certs and keys. $
>   sudo kubeadm alpha phase certs apiserver --apiserver-advertise-address
>    $ sudo kubeadm alpha phase certs
>   apiserver-kubelet-client $ sudo kubeadm alpha phase certs
>   front-proxy-client Backup old configuration files $ sudo mv
>   /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf.old $ sudo mv
>   /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf.old $ sudo
>   mv /etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf
>   /etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf.old $ sudo mv
>   /etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf /etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf.old
>   Generate new configuration files. There is an important note here. If
>   you are on AWS, you will need to explicitly pass the --node-name
>   parameter in this request. Otherwise you will get an error like:
>   Unable to register node "ip-10-0-8-141.ec2.internal" with API server:
>   nodes "ip-10-0-8-141.ec2.internal" is forbidden: node ip-10-0-8-141
>   cannot modify node ip-10-0-8-141.ec2.internal in your logs sudo
>   journalctl -u kubelet --all | tail and the Master Node will report
>   that it is Not Ready when you run kubectl get nodes.
>
> Please be certain to replace the values passed in
>   --apiserver-advertise-address and --node-name with the correct values for your environment.
>
> $ sudo kubeadm alpha phase kubeconfig all
>   --apiserver-advertise-address 10.0.8.141 --node-name ip-10-0-8-141.ec2.internal [kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk:
>   "admin.conf" [kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk:
>   "kubelet.conf" [kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk:
>   "controller-manager.conf" [kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk:
>   "scheduler.conf"
>
> Ensure that your kubectl is looking in the right place for your config
>   files. $ mv .kube/config .kube/config.old $ sudo cp -i
>   /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config $ sudo chown $(id
>   -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config $ sudo chmod 777 $HOME/.kube/config $ export KUBECONFIG=.kube/config Reboot your master node $ sudo
>   /sbin/shutdown -r now Reconnect to your master node and grab your
>   token, and verify that your Master Node is "Ready". Copy the token to
>   your clipboard. You will need it in the next step. $ kubectl get nodes
>   $ kubeadm token list If you do not have a valid token. You can create
>   one with:
>
> $ kubeadm token create The token should look something like
>   6dihyb.d09sbgae8ph2atjw
>
> SSH into each of the slave nodes and reconnect them to the master $
>   sudo curl -sSL
>   https://dl.k8s.io/release/v1.8.15/bin/linux/amd64/kubeadm >
>   ./kubeadm.1.8.15 $ chmod a+rx kubeadm.1.8.15 $ sudo mv
>   /usr/bin/kubeadm /usr/bin/kubeadm.1.7 $ sudo mv kubeadm.1.8.15
>   /usr/bin/kubeadm $ sudo kubeadm join --token=  : --node-name
>
> Repeat Step 9 for each connecting node. From the master node, you can
>   verify that all slave nodes have connected and are ready with: $
>   kubectl get nodes Hopefully this gets you where you need to be
>   @davidcomeyne.

Comment: I don't know if this works yet, I'll report back after I'm done copy pasting a ton of commands into my shell.

Comment: /etc/kubernetes/pki doesn't exist... so I just won't be backing these things up I guess.

Answer (score 0):

As root try first a full clean up with:

```
minikube delete --all --purge
```

Then start up minikube and you need to copy the root certs for another users.