# Kubectl with minikube - Error restarting cluster: kubeadm.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have kubernetes + minicube installed (MacOs 10.12.6) installed. But while trying to start the minicube i get constant errors:

```
$: minikube start
Starting local Kubernetes v1.10.0 cluster...
Starting VM...
Getting VM IP address...
Moving files into cluster...
Setting up certs...
Connecting to cluster...
Setting up kubeconfig...
Starting cluster components...
E0601 15:24:50.571967   67567 start.go:281] Error restarting cluster:  running cmd:
sudo kubeadm alpha phase certs all --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml &&
sudo /usr/bin/kubeadm alpha phase kubeconfig all --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml &&
sudo /usr/bin/kubeadm alpha phase controlplane all --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml &&
sudo /usr/bin/kubeadm alpha phase etcd local --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml
: Process exited with status 1
```

I've also tried to do `minikube delete` and the `minikube start` that didn't help ([Minikube never start - Error restarting cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50554009/minikube-never-start-error-restarting-cluster/50566528)). Also `kubectl config use-context minikube` was done.

I have minikube version: v0.26.1

It looks to me that kubeadm.yaml file is missing or misplaced.

Comment: Same problem, I ssh'ed into the VM and ran "sudo kubeadm alpha phase certs all --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml" The result was "failure loading apiserver-kubelet-client certificate: the certificate has expired"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minikube never start - Error restarting cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50554009/minikube-never-start-error-restarting-cluster)

Answer (score 2):

[Minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/minikube/) is a tool that makes it easy to run Kubernetes locally. Minikube runs a single-node Kubernetes cluster inside a VM on your laptop for users looking to try out Kubernetes or develop with it day-to-day.

In your issue, below steps should do the initialization process successfully:

```
minikube stop

minikube delete

rm -fr $HOME/.minikube

minikube start
```

In the case you mixed Kubernetes and minikube environments I suggest to inspect $HOME/.kube/config file
and delete minikube entries to avoid problem with reinitialization.

If minikube still refuses to start please post logs to analyze. To get detailed log start minikube this way:

```
minikube start --v=9
```

Comment: I've tried to stop/delete/start - but that didn't help as I wrote in the topic. Yesterday I've managed to start with following cmd: `minikube start --vm-driver=hyperkit --bootstrapper=localkube` but now will try your snippet