# minikube error trying to reach 172.17.0.4:8080 on osx

Tags: macos, kubernetes, minikube

I'm doing the kubernetes tutorial locally with minikube on osx. In https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/deploy-app/deploy-interactive/ step 3, I get the error

```
% curl http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/$POD_NAME/proxy/
Error: 'dial tcp 172.17.0.4:8080: getsockopt: connection refused'
Trying to reach: 'http://172.17.0.4:8080/'%
```

any idea why this doesn't work locally? the simpler request does work

```
% curl http://localhost:8001/version
{
  "major": "1",
  "minor": "10",
  "gitVersion": "v1.10.0",
  "gitCommit": "fc32d2f3698e36b93322a3465f63a14e9f0eaead",
  "gitTreeState": "clean",
  "buildDate": "2018-03-26T16:44:10Z",
  "goVersion": "go1.9.3",
  "compiler": "gc",
  "platform": "linux/amd64"
```

info

```
$ kubectl get pods                                          
NAME                                   READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
kubernetes-bootcamp-74f58d6b87-ntn5r   0/1       ImagePullBackOff   0          21h
```

logs

```
$ kubectl logs $POD_NAME
Error from server (BadRequest): container "kubernetes-bootcamp" in pod "kubernetes-bootcamp-74f58d6b87-w4zh8" is waiting to start: trying and failing to pull image
```

so then the run command is starting the node but the pod crashes? why?

```
$ kubectl run kubernetes-bootcamp --image=gcr.io/google-samples/kubernetes-bootcamp:v1 --port=8080
```

I can pull the image without a problem

```
$ docker pull gcr.io/google-samples/kubernetes-bootcamp:v1
v1: Pulling from google-samples/kubernetes-bootcamp
5c90d4a2d1a8: Pull complete 
ab30c63719b1: Pull complete 
29d0bc1e8c52: Pull complete 
d4fe0dc68927: Pull complete 
dfa9e924f957: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:0d6b8ee63bb57c5f5b6156f446b3bc3b3c143d233037f3a2f00e279c8fcc64af
Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/google-samples/kubernetes-bootcamp:v1
```

describe

```
$ kubectl describe pods                                      
Name:           kubernetes-bootcamp-74f58d6b87-w4zh8
Namespace:      default
Node:           minikube/10.0.2.15
Start Time:     Tue, 24 Jul 2018 15:05:00 -0400
Labels:         pod-template-hash=3091482643
                run=kubernetes-bootcamp
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Pending
IP:             172.17.0.3
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/kubernetes-bootcamp-74f58d6b87
Containers:
  kubernetes-bootcamp:
    Container ID:   
    Image:          gci.io/google-samples/kubernetes-bootcamp:v1
    Image ID:       
    Port:           8080/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ImagePullBackOff
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-wp28q (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  Initialized    True 
  Ready          False 
  PodScheduled   True 
Volumes:
  default-token-wp28q:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-wp28q
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason   Age                 From               Message
  ----     ------   ----                ----               -------
  Normal   BackOff  23m (x281 over 1h)  kubelet, minikube  Back-off pulling image "gci.io/google-samples/kubernetes-bootcamp:v1"
  Warning  Failed   4m (x366 over 1h)   kubelet, minikube  Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

Comment: Is the pod actually running?  Does `kubectl logs $POD_NAME` say anything interesting?  That error message sounds like either the pod hasn't started up or it's misconfigured; the process in the pod needs to be listening on 0.0.0.0:8080.

Comment: yes, the tutorial also has you run `kubectl get pods` and the pod is running

Comment: In your output, the pod is NOT running:

> kubernetes-bootcamp-74f58d6b87-ntn5r   0/1

Comment: You can use the command `kubectl cluster-info` to get all the information about the cluster and check if the proxy is existing. And you can use the command `curl http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/kubernetes-bootcamp-79c8445fcb-72cfd/` to get the pod information through API.

Answer (score 2):

[Minikube](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube) is a tool that makes it easy to run [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io) locally.

Minikube runs a single-node Kubernetes 
cluster inside a VM on your laptop for users looking to try out Kubernetes or develop with it day-to-day.

Back to your issue. Have you checked if you provided enough resources to run Minikube environment?

You may try to run minikube and force allocate more memory:

```
minikube start --memory 4096
```

For further analysis, please provide information about resources dedicated to this installation and
type of hypervisor you use.

Comment: How do I collect information about my environment? are you on osx and following the tutorial?

Comment: following http://kubernetesbyexample.com/pods/ I've determined that the ip address for the pod is 172.17.0.4:8080

Comment: What hypervisor did you use when installing minikube and how much RAM do you have on your Mac?

Comment: not sure what hypervisor, virtualbox? I'm on a mac with 16gb ram and chrome with several tabs open.

Comment: may i propose you to: [restart minikube environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50644582/kubectl-with-minikube-error-restarting-cluster-kubeadm-yaml/50685531#50685531)?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a networking issue. Your VM is unable to pull the images from gcr.io:443.

Here's what your `kubectl describe pods kubernetes-bootcamp-xxx` should looks like:

```
  Type    Reason                 Age   From               Message
  ----    ------                 ----  ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled              5m    default-scheduler  Successfully assigned kubernetes-bootcamp-5c69669756-xbbmn to minikube
  Normal  SuccessfulMountVolume  5m    kubelet, minikube  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-cfq65"
  Normal  Pulling                5m    kubelet, minikube  pulling image "gcr.io/google-samples/kubernetes-bootcamp:v1"
  Normal  Pulled                 5m    kubelet, minikube  Successfully pulled image "gcr.io/google-samples/kubernetes-bootcamp:v1"
  Normal  Created                5m    kubelet, minikube  Created container
  Normal  Started                5m    kubelet, minikube  Started container
  Normal  SuccessfulMountVolume  1m    kubelet, minikube  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-cfq65"
  Normal  SandboxChanged         1m    kubelet, minikube  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Normal  Pulled                 1m    kubelet, minikube  Container image "gcr.io/google-samples/kubernetes-bootcamp:v1" already present on machine
  Normal  Created                1m    kubelet, minikube  Created container
  Normal  Started                1m    kubelet, minikube  Started container
```

Try this from your host, to narrow down if it's a networking issue with your VM or your host machine:

```
$ docker pull gcr.io/google-samples/kubernetes-bootcamp:v1
v1: Pulling from google-samples/kubernetes-bootcamp
5c90d4a2d1a8: Pull complete
ab30c63719b1: Pull complete
29d0bc1e8c52: Pull complete
d4fe0dc68927: Pull complete
dfa9e924f957: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:0d6b8ee63bb57c5f5b6156f446b3bc3b3c143d233037f3a2f00e279c8fcc64af
Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/google-samples/kubernetes-bootcamp:v1
```