# Minikube with basic-auth fails to start

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to test basic authentication with latest minikube and it fails to start.

First I start minikube with the following

```
minikube --cpus 6 --memory 10000 --alsologtostderr start --kubernetes-version="v1.13.0" --vm-driver=virtualbox
```

Once running I then use `minikube ssh` and create the file `/var/lib/minikube/certs/mini/users.csv` with the contents `somepassword,johndoe,johndoe123,developers`

ie.

```
$ ls -lat /var/lib/minikube/certs/mini/users.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 43 Dec  9 21:31 /var/lib/minikube/certs/mini/users.csv
$ more /var/lib/minikube/certs/mini/users.csv 
somepassword,johndoe,johndoe123,developers
```

I then `minikube stop` and restart as follows

```
minikube --cpus 6 --memory 10000 --alsologtostderr start --kubernetes-version="v1.13.0" --vm-driver=virtualbox \
--extra-config=apiserver.basic-auth-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/mini/users.csv
```

This resulted in the following error

```
I1209 21:33:34.716833    7099 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/minikube/certs/
I1209 21:33:34.775015    7099 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo rm -f /var/lib/minikube/certs/proxy-client.key
I1209 21:33:34.820764    7099 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/minikube/certs/
I1209 21:33:34.878749    7099 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo rm -f /var/lib/minikube/kubeconfig
I1209 21:33:34.928998    7099 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/minikube
Connecting to cluster...
Setting up kubeconfig...
I1209 21:33:35.231167    7099 config.go:125] Using kubeconfig:  /home/paulhopkins/.kube/config
Starting cluster components...
I1209 21:33:35.235662    7099 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: 
sudo kubeadm alpha phase certs all --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml &&
sudo /usr/bin/kubeadm alpha phase kubeconfig all --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml &&
sudo /usr/bin/kubeadm alpha phase controlplane all --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml &&
sudo /usr/bin/kubeadm alpha phase etcd local --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml

E1209 21:33:35.268920    7099 start.go:302] Error restarting cluster:  running cmd: 
sudo kubeadm alpha phase certs all --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml &&
sudo /usr/bin/kubeadm alpha phase kubeconfig all --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml &&
sudo /usr/bin/kubeadm alpha phase controlplane all --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml &&
sudo /usr/bin/kubeadm alpha phase etcd local --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml
: Process exited with status 1
```

I can still ssh into minikube and `kubeadm.yaml` is as follows:

```
$ sudo more /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml 
apiEndpoint:
  advertiseAddress: 192.168.99.107
  bindPort: 8443
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1alpha3
bootstrapTokens:
- groups:
  - system:bootstrappers:kubeadm:default-node-token
  ttl: 24h0m0s
  usages:
  - signing
  - authentication
kind: InitConfiguration
nodeRegistration:
  criSocket: /var/run/dockershim.sock
  name: minikube
  taints: []
---
apiServerExtraArgs:
  basic-auth-file: "/var/lib/minikube/certs/mini/users.csv"
  enable-admission-plugins: "Initializers,NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,DefaultStorageClass,DefaultTolerationSeconds,NodeRestriction,MutatingAdmissionWebhook,ValidatingAdmissionWebhook,ResourceQuota"

apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1alpha3
certificatesDir: /var/lib/minikube/certs/
clusterName: kubernetes
controlPlaneEndpoint: localhost:8443
etcd:
  local:
    dataDir: /data/minikube
kind: ClusterConfiguration
kubernetesVersion: v1.13.0
networking:
  dnsDomain: cluster.local
  podSubnet: ""
  serviceSubnet: 10.96.0.0/12$
```

Minikube version is v0.30.0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is seems to be similar like there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50554009/minikube-never-start-error-restarting-cluster

Comment: What do you get if you run all the commands manually? `sudo kubeadm alpha phase certs all --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml`....etc

Comment: @Rico bizarrely I get the following `$ sudo kubeadm alpha phase certs all --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml`

`Error: unknown flag: --config`

`Usage:`

Comment: @VitezslavSimon Thanks for the link. Yes the error message is similar. Unfortunately the solution is to delete and recreate which doesn't seem to help. I also don't see any error log information that helps either

Comment: @P Hopkins, Have you removed `$HOME/.minikube` after `minikube delete` command? Try to verbose `minikube start --v=9` to get more specific events during cluster's start up.

Comment: @mk_sta Exactly the same result unfortunately. debug output seems to only show ssh and vboxmanage output. nothing helpful

Comment: @P Hopkins, I would check also `kubelet` logs: `journalctl -u kubelet`, `systemctl status kubelet -l`.